# logic to run set of bat files

Tags: python, batch-file

I have python code that does this:

1. Write type A BAT files ( say abat1,abat2..)
2. Run type A BAT files using dos command "start abat1".. and so on
3. Some other code.
4. Write type B BAT files ( say bbat1,bbat2..)
5. Run type B BAT files using dos command "start bbat1"

The problem here is that I am unable to implement a logic where I want to make sure that bbat1 should start running only after abat1 has finished since there are some dependencies.Similarly for other type A and B bat files.

Is any logic like this possible in bat file or in the python code itself?

Note: I cannot use "start/wait" due to requirements of running all the type A files in parallel. The "wait" I want is between type A and type B files.

Comment: Please **show** your code instead of describing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a file indicator:

- abat

  ```
  type nul>running.ind
  rem here is the code of your abat
  del running.ind
  ```
- bbat

  ```
  :loop
  if not exist running.ind goto :main
  rem wait fife seconds
  ping -n 6 localhost >nul
  goto :loop
  :main
  rem more code here
  ```

Instead of a file, you can do this also with a registry key.

Comment: Sorry I am new to bat files. One thing I wanted to ask: As I understand I would need to create a file .ind first and this could be empty. I would test this. Thanks.